# packer - cannot shutdown virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, packer

I am trying to close virtual machine using command

"shutdown_command": "echo 'packer' | sudo -S shutdown -P now"

But it returns:

virtualbox-ovf: sudo: shutdown: command not found

How to properly shutdown the VM ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how you created your `packer` user (btw, its usually vagrant as user, not packer) but the user is not able to find `shutdown` command, the `PATH` variable might have been unset.

`shutdown` is generally under `/sbin` or `/usr/sbin` (depending distros) so to quickly fix your issue you should be able to run

```
"shutdown_command": "echo 'packer' | sudo -S /sbin/shutdown -P now"
```

If not, check where shutdown is installed (`whereis shutdown`) and replaced with this location